# List of sites that still dont support HSTS?

Tags: tls, web-browser, http, webserver, hsts

I'm working on an article for work and seeking a list of the top ~500 websites (ranked by [Alexa](https://www.alexa.com/)) that still don't have support for HSTS. Does such a list exist? I'm not getting any interesting hits from my Google queries.

Other than *check all the websites one-by-one*, would anyone be able to offer a method for accomplishing this?

Comment: It would be pretty easy to script this, I'd imagine.

Comment: What would one look for in such a script? I'm a decent BASH coder, I could try to create something automated GET requests, but how would know if a particular queried site was using HSTS or not?

Comment: You could use `curl` to make a HTTP request, and check the HTTP response headers for the `Strict-Transport-Security` header.

Comment: Regular or static HSTS? Static HSTS is compiled into a list, but far fewer websites use static HSTS.

Comment: script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717789/how-to-find-if-a-web-site-uses-hsts

Comment: @user178357 You would want to use HEAD requests, not GET.

Comment: This is an old question but... If you're going to use the likes of `curl` in your script, you may want to spoof the `User-Agent` header in order to masquerade as a browser. For instance, at the time of writing, navigating to `https://www.google.com` in a browser returns a response with an STS header, but the output of `curl -I https://www.google.com` contains no such header.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you already have a newline-delimited list of domain names you wish to check, use a script such as this one which takes the list in a file specified by the first argument or stdin:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r s; do
    curl -sI "https://$s" | grep -qiE "^Strict-Transport-Security:" || echo "$s"
done < "${1:-/dev/stdin}"

exit 0
```

This will output a list of domains to stdout that are up, but which do not send the standard HSTS headers over HTTPS. This does not mean that certain subdomains do not use HSTS, and it does not mean that all the sites which do send HSTS headers are doing so correctly. Checking whether or not the HSTS is [syntactically valid](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-6.1) would require much more complex regex.

Answer (score 2):

## Dynamic HSTS

[@forest's](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/165253/forest) [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/186095/159064) covers this well, so not to retread ground, you will want to connect to each site and check the returned headers, this could be done using HEAD if you wish to reduce the amount of data sent back.

## Static HSTS

### Firefox

You will want to use one of the following links:

- **Release**

  https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-release/raw-file/tip/security/manager/ssl/nsSTSPreloadList.inc
- **Beta**

  https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-beta/raw-file/tip/security/manager/ssl/nsSTSPreloadList.inc

### Chrome

Chrome is slightly harder, first you need to use this:

https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/all.json

to find the hash for a given release, then load

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/**hash**/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json?format=TEXT

where hash is the hash you got from the previous step.

You'll need to Base64 decode the result.